# Why am I getting "YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry" on AWS Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am starting to learn/work with AWS and Cloudformation, I have this:

```
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
Properties:
 SecurityGroupIds:
    - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
 SubnetId: 
     !Ref "PublicSubnet1"
 IamInstanceProfile:
     !Ref RootInstanceProfile
 ImageId: ami-02cb52d7ba9887a93
 InstanceType: t3.micro
 UserData:
   Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    # Install Apache Web Server and PHP
      yum install -y httpd mysql
      amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2
    # Download Lab files
      wget https://us-west-2-tcprod.s3.amazonaws.com/courses/ILT-TF-100-ARCHIT/v6.5.0/lab-2-webapp/scripts/inventory-app.zip
      unzip inventory-app.zip -d /var/www/html/
    # Download and install the AWS SDK for PHP
      wget https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/download/3.62.3/aws.zip
      unzip aws -d /var/www/html
    # Turn on web server
      chkconfig httpd on
      service httpd start
```

When I try to create the stack I receive an identention error at UserData:

Any advice or tip?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have **indentation issue** in your `UserData` which is clear from your code. It should be (you also don't need `Sub`):

```
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
Properties:
 SecurityGroupIds:
    - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
 SubnetId: 
     !Ref "PublicSubnet1"
 IamInstanceProfile:
     !Ref RootInstanceProfile
 ImageId: ami-02cb52d7ba9887a93
 InstanceType: t3.micro
 UserData:
   Fn::Base64: |
      #!/bin/bash
      # Install Apache Web Server and PHP
      yum install -y httpd mysql
      amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2
      # Download Lab files
      wget https://us-west-2-tcprod.s3.amazonaws.com/courses/ILT-TF-100-ARCHIT/v6.5.0/lab-2-webapp/scripts/inventory-app.zip
      unzip inventory-app.zip -d /var/www/html/
      # Download and install the AWS SDK for PHP
      wget https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/download/3.62.3/aws.zip
      unzip aws -d /var/www/html
      # Turn on web server
      chkconfig httpd on
      service httpd start
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but it stills give me an error on the properties of the AWS::EC2::Instance.

Comment: @JesusPeña No problem. Which error? Could be also due to indentation. Please double check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this as an example](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/a1d780188cc1cdd39e732257380d5deb) for writing the userdata in cloudformation template.

Use [cfn-linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) for generating the template, there are plenty of good examples in the documentation as well.

[Github Search](https://github.com/search?l=YAML&q=%27Fn%3A%3ABase64%3A+%21Sub%27&type=Code) always results into working examples.

The linter can be installed as a plugin in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or you can run it from your command line the above one.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time. I still can not find the error. I keep working on it. Have a good day